# 404 error on new pages with wordpress blog ( on mysql) with django (postgres) using nginx on the same server

Tags: django, wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-404

Condition :
I have set up my server as follows :
my wordpress blog ( on mysql) with
django (postgres)
using nginx on the same server.

Error

1. I am getting 404 error for new pages I create on the blog. ( it works when permalink settings is like this : https://www.example.com/blog/?p=1
2. It does not work when permalink setting contains post name
3. New pages I create also behave in similar fashion - do not work with name slug

My analysis is that it has something to do with ssl conf or nginx conf. Basically routing issue. I am a newbie.

Here is the Nginx Conf:

```
upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/user/opt/env/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

#wordpress php handler
upstream wordpress-prod-php-handler {
    server unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

```
# serve wordpress from subdirectory
        location /blog {
        alias /home/user/opt/blog;
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
        location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
          fastcgi_pass wordpress-prod-php-handler;
        }
    }
```

Please help..

As specified, I was trying to get my blog and app on the same domain.

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) -> opens django app
[www.example.com/blog](http://www.example.com/blog) -> opens wordpress blog

Now it works fine, but if anything comes after /blog -- such as example.com/blog/test will result in a 404 error.

Nginx error log shows this :
2022/12/31 14:04:01 [error] 24005#24005: *3968 open() "/usr/share/nginx/htmlindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 122.161.15.206, server: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), request: "GET /blog/7-reasons-for-xyz/ HTTP/2.0", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/blog/"